# How can I integrate Gerrit with HipChat

Tags: continuous-integration, gerrit, hipchat

Do you have any tips or tutorials how to integrate **Gerrit** with **HipChat** to send specific information about code review process/build/tests?

Comment: Just google "Gerrit with HipChat" and find this: http://www.thedroidsonroids.com/blog/integrate-gerrit-hipchat/